# What are these values printed by Log.d("LOG","Value of v: " + v) and how do I use them? Android

Tags: android, debugging, button, layout, android-framelayout

If I have an onClick for example:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    Log.d("LOG","Value of v: " + v);
}
```

I am getting the below output:

```
v android.widget.Button{424b9f10 VFED..C. ...P.... 0,2-70,72 #7f0a0080 app:id/rowButtonRemove}
```

I was reading android.widget.Button's android reference documents, but still couldn't figure out what they are, but what I know for sure is that I want to grab this particular unique value "424b9f10" somehow and store it into a variable. Can someone tell me what it is, and how I can put it into a variable?

Comment: can you explain me why you want to use this value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use  this

```
String s = v.gettext().toString();
```

and after that you can set that in some text view o where ever you want.

for example

```
text1.settext(s);
```

Try this and please let me know

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to log an object and you shouldn't do that!
you can use `v.getId()` instead.